# Что за конструкция на месте определения?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Глядя *на **внушительных размеров** преграду*, возникала...
>
> ... как это всегда бывает *на **подобного рода** мероприятиях* ...

Выделенные жирным обороты замещают позицию определения при существительном,  при этом из какого-либо разумного согласования выбиваются.

Помогите разобраться, что это за обороты такие.

Comment: Не могу вообразить, как кто-либо (неодушевленный предмет глядеть не может) возникал, глядя на преграду. Может, это сленг (возникать = ругаться)?

Comment: Скорее всего, здесь ошибка в построении предложения с деепричастным оборотом:Глядя на внушительных размеров преграду, возникала  мысль...по примеру "Проезжая мимо дома, у меня с головы слетела шляпа" Предложение полностью писать надо.

Answer (score 2):

**Это инверсия несогласованного определения:** глядя на преграду ***внушительных размеров***,  возникала...

Нормальная позиция несогласованного определения ― после определяемого слова.

**Инверсия согласованных определений делается очень часто,** например: осень ***золотая*** в гости к нам пришла. Нормальная позиция согласованного определения ― перед определяемым словом.

Инверсия ― средство художественной выразительности, способ выделить слово и придать ему особую значимость.

Comment: А нет ли в первом примере инверсии бытия и небытия? Чтобы начать "глядеть", надо сначала "возникнуть".

Comment: Чтобы разобраться  с инверсией такого рода, надо хотя бы всё предложение прочитать, а нам авторы одни фрагменты предлагают.